# Highlight newly uncovered content in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am looking for an effect like the following:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Highlight new stuff}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> [{\Large \textbf{Points}}]
    \item<1-> Foo1
    \item<2-> Foo2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. You can use `<2-| alert@2>` instead of `<2->` and likewise for `<1->`. There are shorter ways like using `\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>] \item \item \end{enumerate}`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.